# What is the public URL for the Github public keys

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, ssh-keys, public-key

I heard that there was a public URL for all users on github where you can access their public keys or they can supply that URL of all their public keys. Is this true? If so what is that URL. Does it exist for bitbucket as well?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can get with:

```
curl https://github.com/<username>.keys
```

Replace `<username>` with the actual username of the GitHub user.

This is useful when you set login permission to other servers. Just save its output into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. To append it to the end from the command line:

```
curl https://github.com/<username>.keys | tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

It can also be done using Github API

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/users/<username>/keys
```

For bit bucket you can use the following: (This call requires authentication.)

```
curl -i https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/users/<accountname>/ssh-keys
```

Comment: If I know a git public key URL, how can I get access or clone the repository?

Comment: @HàLink The public keys belong to users not repositories. I you already know the user it is pretty simple to clone all the user's public repositories.

Comment: Thanks, I have misunderstood the usage of the public key.

Comment: This also works for enterprise versions of github. e.g. <enterprise url>/<username>.keys

Comment: It seems the Bitbucket curl doesn't work, it gives me 403 forbidden.

Comment: @holmb, according to the latest documentation, this endpoint requires authentication. I think this changed over time, I can't recall it being so when I first posted this answer. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/ssh-keys-resource-296911735.html#ssh-keysResource-GET/users/{accountname}/ssh-keys

Comment: @fazras: Please do update the answer regarding BitBucket's change. Thanks.

Comment: @ShaneGannon In my enterprise GitHub it does not work. Perhaps it has been disabled.

Comment: @dzieciou I'm not a GitHub admin but it sounds like something that might be disabled in some orgs. It still is open in our enterprise GitHub.

Answer (score 49):

GPG public keys are now available at `https://github.com/<username>.gpg`

Answer (score 10):

Works for gitlab same way too.

```
https://gitlab.com/<username>.keys
```

Works nicely in bash scripts too.

```
#GitProvider to fetch public keys (gitlab.com,github.com)
GitProvider="gitlab.com"
GitUsername="username"
curl https://${GitProvider}/${GitUsername}.keys | tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 10):

In addition these also provide a way to retrieve a user's PGP keys:

**GitHub**:

```
https://github.com/USER.keys
https://gitlab.com/USER.gpg
```

**GitLab**:

```
https://gitlab.com/USER.keys
https://gitlab.com/USER.gpg
```

Answer (score -2):

While the keys are *public* you don't always want to reveal your internal hostnames from the default comment fields, so I'd recommend `ssh-copy-id` command if you have SSH password access, `wormhole` when on console and configuration management tools (like Ansible, Puppet etc) in the first place.