# how to send somebody my (already generated) github public rsa key(send the key or the .pub file?)

Tags: git, github, rsa, ssh-keys

I just set up `Github` and generated my `ssh keys`. I need to give my public `rsa` to somebody so they can allow me access to their git repo. Do I send them

a) my entire `.pub` file,

b) the contents of the `.pub` file, or

c) the key that i see if i log in to `Github` and go to ssh keys(looks like: `id_rsa (22:ac:74:6b:a7:d9:14:a5:32:8f:08:c5:51:1b:49:lk`)

Comment: That `22:ac:...` bit is the so-called fingerprint of your public key -- a cryptographic digest of the key's contents which allows to represent the key in a succint human-readable form while being unique for each key.

Comment: There are a list of keys on my github account under the SSH keys part. How do I know which ones are private keys and which ones are public keys? I see some of them have a green dot next to them. But even if I know which ones are private and which ones are public, how do I even get their contents and send them if the : : : format is just for human readability?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Send the contents of id_rsa.pub or the file id_rsa.pub itself. Either way. (Also: Remember never to send your private key.)

Comment: alright thats exactly what I was looking for thanks, I'll accept your answer in a couple mins it says I can't accept an answer within 2 minutes

Answer (score 1):

If they know your username, they can get your public key already. See [What is the public URL for the Github public keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158158/what-is-the-public-url-for-the-github-public-keys).

This could also be handled by them adding you as a collaborator via the repo settings at https://github.com/username/repo/settings/collaboration