# What is the public URL for the GitHub GPG keys

Tags: git, github, gnupg

Is there a simple endpoint for retrieving a users gpg public key?

For SSH keys, `github.com/<username>.keys`, is there something similar for gpg keys?

Related: [What is the public URL for the Github public keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158158/what-is-the-public-url-for-the-github-public-keys)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using the [GitHub API for GPG Keys](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/gpg_keys/#list-gpg-keys-for-a-user):

> ### List GPG keys for a user
>
> ```
> GET /users/:username/gpg_keys
> ```
>
> Lists the GPG keys for a user. This information is accessible by anyone.

[weiji14](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6611055/weiji14) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184895/what-is-the-public-url-for-the-github-gpg-keys/49187371#comment91592958_49187371):

> You can get the keys via the command line using
>
> ```
> curl https://api.github.com/users/<username>/gpg_keys
> ```

---

Since Oct. 2021 and [GitHub CLI `gh` 2.2.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.2.0), you also have [`gh gpg-key list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_gpg-key_list):

```
gh gpg-key list [flags]
```

Comment: You can get the keys via the command line using `curl https://api.github.com/users/<username>/gpg_keys`

Comment: @weiji14 Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 20):

If you do not want to use the API, because you do not want to process the data returned, you can get a raw key from:

```sh
curl https://github.com/<username>.gpg
```

The output can be used directly for import.

```sh
$ curl https://github.com/web-flow.gpg | gpg --import
```

Comment: Where is this documented? There is also <username>.keys. What else is out there?

Answer (score 1):

Also `github.com/<username>.gpg` works, at least within GHE it does, I haven't verified on public github